# Building in VC6, need unsigned long long

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

I need to build a purchased library (with source) that was built in VC 2010.  We have to build with VC6.  I ran across signed and unsigned "long long".  I am using "_int64" for the signed type but was unable to find anything for the unsigned type.  Has anyone run across a solution?  Apologies if this is documented, I have had no luck in finding anything.

Comment: I'm not sure why you had "no luck finding anything", it's [right there on the `__int64` documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261215%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__int64` is a vendor-specific base type.  It can be combined with the `unsigned` modifier, just like:

```
 unsigned char               unsigned __int8
 unsigned short              unsigned __int16
 unsigned int                unsigned __int32
 unsigned long               unsigned __int32
(unsigned long long)         unsigned __int64
                            (unsigned __int128)
```

Where the parenthesized names are not available in VC6, but are supported in the current version of Visual C++.